# List the surnames of bosses who manage at least two employees from the query below

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the surnames of bosses who manage at least two employees from the query below that earn no more than twice the average earnings of ALL people they direct.
I'm stuck here:

```
SELECT surname from emp k INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT surname, base_salary
   from emp p LEFT JOIN 
     (select id_team, avg(base_salary) as s, count(*) as c from emp group by id_team)
        as o ON(p.id_team = o.id_team)
          where p.base_salary between o.s*0.7 and o.s*1.3 and o.c >=2) l ON (k.id_boss = o.id_boss)
having count(k.id_boss) >2 ??? AND k.base_salary < ????
```

I hope you get my point. Any advices how could I do that?
Here's what the full table looks like:

[image: All people]

Comment: you should also add the expected  result

Comment: It's much, much easier for us if you provide sample data as text, not image. Even easier when you provide [dbfiddle like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4747a828d4e1082897b12d824b49c1b4). This way we can focus on solution and test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem which I'm having is following - I have a query that gives me the list of employees (name, base_salary) that earn an average value (with accuracy up to 30%) from the average earnings in teams of > 2 employees.  And I need to get the surnames of bosses who manage at least two employees from that filtred results, furthermore  they have to earn no more than twice the average earnings of ALL people they employ ignoring filtered results. And I don't know how to handle that. I've tried multiple things, and nothing works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eab2b3/8

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you should just add the proper having clause
having count(k.id_boss) >2  AND k.base_salary < 2*l.s

```
SELECT k.surname 
from emp k 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT surname, base_salary, id_boss
    from emp p 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        select id_team, avg(base_salary) as s, count(*) as c
        from emp 
        group by id_team
    )  o ON p.id_team = o.id_team
    where p.base_salary between o.s*0.7 and o.s*1.3 and o.c >=2
) l ON  k.id_boss = o.id_boss 
group by k.surname 
having count(l.id_boss) >2 
    AND k.base_salary < 2*l.s
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I'm getting ORA-00904: "O"."ID_BOSS": invalid identifier

Comment: Still the same though.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my query? It has to list the employees (name, base_salary) that earn an average value (with accuracy up to 30%) from the average earnings in teams of >2 employees. Alone it works, though.